# Passing Object Functions To Object Constructor

Tags: javascript, function

Apologies for the title, but there's no succinct way of putting it. I'm working on the following code, which aims to chain a set of counters together, into one big one. To build a clock or whatever.

```
function subcounter(max, name, trigger) {
    this.index = 0;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.name = name;

    this.tick = function() {
        this.index++;
        if (this.index==max) {
            this.index=0;
            this.trigger();
        }
    }

    this.show = function() {
        alert(this.name+' triggered');
    }
}

y = new subcounter(2,'y',function(){alert('finished')});
x = new subcounter(2,'x',y.tick);

for (var index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
    alert ([x.index, y.index]);
    x.tick();
}
```

This doesn't work as expected. For debugging I replaced the line above with:

```
x = new subcounter(2,'x',y.show);
```

And found that 'x triggered' is shown instead of 'y triggered', which I would expect. What's going on here? (Tried in Firefox).

---

Thanks for your answers or pointing me to documentation on `this`. However, my brain still fails to understand how a function scoped to one object instance: 'y.show' can ever resolve to that function on a different object instance.

The answer seems to be:

```
x = new subcounter(2,'x',function() {y.tick();});
```

But I'd still like to really understand why the original doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Read `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Fthis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like

```
function subcounter(max, name, trigger) {
    var that = this;
    this.index = 0;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.name = name;

    this.tick = function() {
        that.index++;
        if (that.index==max) {
            that.index=0;
            that.trigger();
        }
    }

    this.show = function() {
        alert(that.name+' triggered');
    }
}
```

Otherwise javascript's local scoping will have `this` contain a reference to the outer context `this` (i.e., `x.this` in your case) in the inner functions.

[Here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) is a post detailing the functioning of javascript's local scoping, but it's just the first result I got, it's a pretty common issue.

Comment: I would love to accept this answer. Except it doesn't work. I still get 'x triggered'.

Comment: Quite strange: I created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/H5Bs3/ with my modified code (and `alert`s replaced with `console.log`s) and it seems to be working.

Comment: I see it's correct there. But both Firefox / IE work 'incorrectly'.

Comment: I see it logging 'y triggered' in FF as well :(

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, it has to do with what the value of 'this' will be inside a function.

Inside a function 'this' will be the value of the object in which the function is called from.

When you call this.trigger(),this is now the object 'x'. So inside the trigger function ie 'show',

```
this.name will be same as x.name
```

To get the y objects value, pass the 'y' object itself and call the show function from that object.

```
function subcounter(max, name, trigger, methodName) {
    this.index = 0;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.name = name;

    this.tick = function() {
        this.index++;
        if (this.index==max) {
            this.index=0;
            this.trigger[methodName]();
        }
    }

    this.show = function() {
        console.log(this.name+' triggered');
    }
}

y = new subcounter(2,'y',function(){alert('finished')});
x = new subcounter(2,'x',y, "show");
```

Comment: This works. However it's inflexible. As you can see, I want to be able to pass ANY function to be triggered.

Comment: @guillermo-phillips I've updated my answer. Now you can pass the object and method name to call.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript changes the scope of `this` when calling a method from within another object context. Have a look at this article:

http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/